# Detecting a shake when Android is asleep and locked with service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, service

I want to wake the android device from its locked and asleep state with a single state.

What should I use?

A wake lock to keep my service running and listening for a shake.

Or is it possible to do the same thing with Flags with a service?

Will the service receive anything if the android device is locked and asleep, if I don't have a wake lock?

Update: is a wake lock ideal or unnecessary?

Comment: Implement it through service

Comment: Yes, but do I need a wake lock or not? Is that the ideal method?

Comment: a wake lock prevents that your device goes to sleep, but you won't get anything from the sensors if it would be asleep, so you probably want one. You can simply try if it works.

Comment: you need a wake lock to prevent system locking screen by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a service that runs on background and listens to your event(shake)

as per flag you can lock and unlock screen

```
//Get the window from the context

 WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);



   //Unlock

    //http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()
 Window window = getWindow();  

   window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  



    //Lock device

   DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

  mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```